# Calculate limit of following function

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim _{x\to \infty }\left(\frac{\left(4x-1\right)^3}{\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)\log \left(1+3x\right)}\right)$$

Not getting how to get started with it.

Comment: what kind of theorems can you use?

Comment: The ratio is not defined for every $x$ large enough. What is the meaning of a limit when $x\to+\infty$ in this context?

Comment: Explicitly, for any $N > 0$, I can find $x = 2\sqrt{\pi} N > N$ such that $$f(x) = \frac{(4x-1)^3}{\sin \frac{x^2}{4} \log (1+3x)}$$ is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$ goes back and forth between $+1$, $0$, and $-1$ forever. So putting that in the denominator means that your answer will bounce between $\pm\infty$ forever without settling on any specific number.